# Print variable issues in php

Tags: php

Print variable issues in php. I need to output variables in a link but its not working. 
Its seems there is either a single or double quote issues. Any help

```
$data=2;
echo "<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'group101.html=$data';
}, 1000);
</script>";
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax, but `group101.html=2` is not a valid URL. If it's a parameter, it should be `group101.html?2`, if it's a hash it should be `group101.html#2`

Comment: tested, above works just fine

Comment: If you want use variable in string with double quotes you need follow syntax: echo "some string {$variable}"

Comment: @korvinko - [no, you don't](https://eval.in/178253)

Comment: @korvinko nothing wrorg with the syntax as it stands.

Comment: If it's a parameter definition it should be `group101.html?myvar=2`

Comment: Thanks everyone in this venerable site